# Par Paragraph Formatter - How to use it in the Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, formatting, paragraph

There is a very smart and useful paragraph formatter **`par`** ([par website](http://www.nicemice.net/par/)). I have used it with Vim and it works great. I would like to use it in Windows command line. (I am using Windows 7). But I get the `par error: bad argument` error. How can I use par in the **windows command prompt**. I already have it in my path, so it does find it and also gives me help content. But I can't figure out why it errors out, when I pass a long text stream to it.

(Since, there is a `par.exe` on the developers website. I am pretty sure that it is meant to work on Windows.)

#### What I have tried is:

```
par w30 "This is a long long paragraph. Please shorten it to 30 characters per line. But it does not work."
par 30j "This is a long long paragraph. Please shorten it to 30 characters per line and also justify the text. But it does not work."
```

I have used it successfully with Vim and it works great. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe input must be piped into the tool, not passed as an argument. So for your examples, try this:

```
echo This is a long long paragraph. Please shorten it to 30 characters per line. But it does not work.| par w30
echo This is a long long paragraph. Please shorten it to 30 characters per line and also justify the text. But it does not work.| par 30j
```